# Why BLAS cblas_sgemm in C is slower than np.dot?

Tags: python, c, numpy, blas

I made a simple benchmark between Python NumPy and C OpenBLAS to multiply two 500x500 matrices. It seems that `np.dot` performs almost 9 times faster than `cblas_sgemm`. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Results:

- Python: 0.001830 seconds
- C: 0.016374 seconds

```py
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(42)
matrix_a = np.random.rand(500, 500)
matrix_b = np.random.rand(500, 500)

start_time = time.time()
result = np.dot(matrix_a, matrix_b)
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"{elapsed_time:.6f} seconds")
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 500

int main(void) {
    srand(42);

    float *matrix_a = (float *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(float));
    float *matrix_b = (float *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(float));
    float *result = (float *)malloc(N * N * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < N * N; ++i) {
        matrix_a[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        matrix_b[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    clock_t start_time = clock();

    cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                N, N, N,
                1.0, matrix_a, N, matrix_b, N,
                0.0, result, N);

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    float elapsed_time = (float)(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f seconds\n", elapsed_time);

    free(matrix_a);
    free(matrix_b);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with

```
cc -lopenblas main.c
```

Also `gcc -O3 -march=native`: 0.016420 seconds

I installed openblas with `brew install openblas` on MacOS 10.15.7. Also the output of `np.show_config()`:

```
openblas64__info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas64__lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

Comment: Didn't you compile with optimisations enabled? With gcc you would use -march=native and -O2 or -O3? I don't know cc.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I expect `cblas_dgemm` to provide a closer analog to your Numpy code than `cblas_sgemm` does.  `double` is C's most natural floating-point type, and I think it's also what Numpy will use by default.

Comment: @SimonGoater I tried and still the same result.

Comment: OpenBLAS is not very well optimized for modern Macs. Try using Apple's Accelerate implementation instead.

Comment: According to my google search, for cc it would be -xo5.

Comment: @SimonGoater - compiler optimizations aren't going to move the needle here because almost all of the runtime is spent in library code. LTO _might_ but that would entail rebuilding OpenBLAS with LTO enabled.

Comment: 1. Try repeated calls. There may be startup overhead. 2. See if you can link with `-lopenblas_openmp` or `-lopenblas_pthreads` instead for the parallelized versions. Probably needs `-fopenmp` or `-pthread` compile switch as well

Comment: @AlexReinking With `<Accelerate/Accelerate.h>` I get 0.007847 sec. Still behind.

Comment: I would follow @Homer512's suggestion and ensure you're using parallel kernels and that the CPU has some time to warm up. Python's interpreter overhead might ramp up the CPU frequency in time for the call, whereas the C version might get there too fast.

Comment: I do not reproduce anything like the performance difference you describe. On Linux (in WSL), I get the numpy version running consistently in about 0.105 s, and the CBLAS version (compiled with `-O3`) running significantly faster, at around 0.062 s.

Comment: @Homer512 Repeated calls tested; same thing. should I install `openblas_pthread`? because I get not found error. `-pthread` also did not change anything.

Comment: You don't check the result of the operation. Have you checked it's returning the correct answer? 1.8ms seems very fast.

Comment: @SimonGoater It is correct for both of them. You can call `print(result)` if you want.

Comment: `clock` does not measure the wall clock time but the (parallel) CPU time. This is not a good measure for a benchmark like this. You must use another function (e.g. like `gettimeofday` for example).

Comment: @SimonGoater Optimizations have no significant impact on the measured time in this case since the target BLAS library is already compiled and the measured code just perform a function call.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks you are right. I get almost 0.0019 average now